# R condition if is not respected

Tags: r

Here is my code :

```
highlightred <- NULL
for (i in values) {
x <- as.numeric(values[i])
if (x > 10 && !is.na(x)) {
  highlightred <- c(highlightred, i)
}    
}
highlightredlight <- NULL
for (i in values) {
x <- as.numeric(values[i])
if (x > 0 && x<=10 && !is.na(x)) {
  highlightredlight <- c(highlightredlight, i)
}    
}
```

values is a list :

```
"2.9" "3.9" "4.9" "5.7" "10.6" "12.3"
```

In highlightred and highlightredlight, I have all the values and I don't understand why the conditioon of my if statement is not respected

Comment: Change `as.numeric(values[i])` to `as.numeric(i)`. `i` is not an iterating integer but the value of the `values` at the current position of the loop.

Comment: @PhillipD Looks like a great answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*i* represent the **current element** in foreach loop. So code should be modified as below.

```
x <- as.numeric(i)
```